# Connecting to Google Drive using Draw.io

Tags: google-drive, app.diagrams.net

When I open draw.io, it does not connect to my Google Drive, and when I click on the button Connect to Google Drive, a pop-up window appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears.
The result is that I cannot access all my drawings.

I have tried with both Firefox and Windows IE, and experienced the same thing in both. I then logged-in to Google Drive and tried to open one of my drawings with draw.io, but it does not work (stuck loading)

Is this a wider issue than just with my account?

Answer (score 2):

Check if you allow 3rd-party cookies in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

I also had trouble with Google Drive and draw.io. I'd click on the draw.io file and it would go to the address and hang up there, a blank white screen. This was in Safari

What worked for me was looking at my list of cookies in

> Safari -> Preferences -> Privacy

and deleting the draw.io cookie.

Comment: Deleting cookies also worked for Chrome. Google for "chrome view cookies" to see how to delete them